# Unexpected token error for cv2 library Pavlovia

Tags: psychopy

I use psychopy to design a picture description experiment where I record the participants’ videos and voices and save them as my output. To record and save videos, I used a code that imports the cv2 library. I used code because the video component in the builder was crashing my experiment, and I read that code would run the video component faster. My experiment works locally but when I try to run it online, my experiment crashes while initializing the experiment. Is there a way to translate my python script to java? Or do you have any alternative suggestions?
Here is my code:
Begin Experiment:

```
import cv2  # this is the OpenCV library for computer vision
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
#out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,  480))
print(expInfo['participant'])
out = cv2.VideoWriter(expInfo['participant'] + '_output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,  480))
webCam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # connect to the zeroth video camera
```

Each Frame:

```
returnVal, frame = webCam.read()
thisMovieFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)/255.0
out.write(frame)
```

I tried importing a set of routines maintained by Thomas Pronk, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cv2 is a Python library. There are other options for recording videos in JS

BUT the latest versions of PsychoPy/JS support video recording and saving in their own classes, with a Builder Component included, so just use those instead!  That also solves for you the issues around saving the data to Pavlovia (and in the local Python version it saves the data in a separate process which would be more efficient than your option of saving the frame within the render loop alongside stimulus rendering)